# SQL query to return an attribute as an array of objects

Tags: mysql, arrays, object, join, nested

My DB (MySQL) looks as follows:

```
TASKS:
-----------------
| id | desc     |      
-----------------
| 1  | 'dishes' |
| 2  | 'dust'   |
-----------------    
IMAGES:
---------------------------
| id | task_id | url      |
---------------------------
| 1  | 1       | 'http1'  |
| 2  | 1       | 'http2'  |
---------------------------
```

I would like to get a response in the following structure (nested array of objects with *id*, *url*):

```
"tasks": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "desc": "dishes",
    "images": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "url": "http1"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "url": "http2"
      }
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

The closest I have got was with this code:

```
SELECT
  t.id,
  t.desc,
  JSON_ARRAYAGG(i.url) AS images,

  FROM tasks AS t
  LEFT JOIN images AS i ON t.id=i.task_id
  GROUP BY t.id
```

And got in return:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "desc": "dishes",
    "images": [
        "http1",
        "http2"
    ]
  }
...
]
```

Above response is problematic as I need the image_ids.

I have also tried using JSON_OBJECTAGG (which is not ideal) however I had below SQL error:

> "JSON documents may not contain NULL member names."

**Indeed some tasks may not have images matching and I want to have them included in the response.**

How should I refactor my code to get the desired response from the server?

Comment: I would be sorely tempted to use a bit of application code

Comment: Do you mean like this:
*getTasks() => forEach getImages(taskId)*?
This is my plan b if quick solution is not found:(

Comment: I don't know what language that is, but yeah, that kind of thing,

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show us your code and tell us, what language you are coding and what did you already try to tackle the problem.